# TfLite: Why is from_saved_model() recommended over from_keras_model()?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tf.keras

The tensorflow guide about the [Tensorflow Lite Converter](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#python_api_) states that using `TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model()` is recommended over `TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model()`.

Why is it recommended?

And what does that mean for converting a Keras model into a TfLite (when the SavedModel does not exist and is not required). Should we still save the Keras model as a `SavedModel` into a temporary folder and convert to TfLite using `.from_saved_model()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backend of the saved model conversion is more capable than the the backends of the other conversion APIs. For example, only the saved model converter can deliver signatures, handle resource and variant tensors and so on. Lucikly, from the TensorFlow 2.7 candidate versions, they will remove those feature gaps among the converter APIs.